# SqlServer Class static methods - Thread Safety

Tags: c#, thread-safety, static-methods

I have created a class to ease the use of SQL server within my app.

```cs
public static class SqlServer
{        
    public static void QueryNoReturn(string ConnectionString, string Query, SqlParameter[] Parameters, bool IsStoredProcedure)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            // Create the command to run
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

            // If we are running a stored procedure
            if (IsStoredProcedure)
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Add parameters if they exist
            if (Parameters != null)
                command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

            try
            {
                // Open the connection to the database
                conn.Open();

                // Execute the command and assign to the result object
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format("{0} \"{1}\"", IsStoredProcedure ? "Procedure" : "Query", Query),
                    sqlex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I am calling this static method many times a second (approx. 50) then will I see issues with thread safety?

I could easily create a `Factory` or some other instance specific object, but I went with this option out of simplicity.

Comment: The comment "// Execute the command and assign to the result object" is broken (there is no assignment happening here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You could get into thread safety problems when you access shared resources, but you don't do that (at least not in this method).

By the way, move the `conn.Close();` to a `finally` clause, that way the connection is closed, even when you get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using any shared resources of the class, this appears to be "thread-safe".

This of course disregards any concurrency issues on the database itself.

You should wrap the `SqlCommand` creation in a `using` statements as well.

Since you are creating the `SqlConnection` in a `using` statement, you don't need to explicitly call `Close` on it, as it will be done when the connection is disposed.